# What plugin should I use to read math expression

Tags: support, mathjax

I am a newbies of this site. Please, help me to read the math expressions in "non-plain" text form like this:

$$a=\left(\sum_i y_i b^{x_i}\right) / \left(\sum_i b^{2x_i}\right)$$

What addin, application will help me to read this and other expressions in "normal" or professional (as msword mentions) form?

Thank you.

**ADDED:**

I saw this one:

[image]

And now I see this one:
[image]

I have resolved this problem by using Google Chrome or [Latex Composer add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/4082/)  for Firefox and [this](http://codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php) editor

Comment: What does "normal" mean? If you need the $\TeX$ code behind, right click on any expression and click "Show Source".

Comment: @J.M. https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/4082/ Thank you!!!

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot or picture of what you are seeing and what you would like to see instead?

Comment: @Rahul Narain I have resolved this problem, see my updated question

Comment: You shouldn't have been seeing that in the first place! Can you try removing the LaTeX Composer plugin and doing a hard refresh (instructions here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Bypass_your_cache#Mozilla_family)?

Comment: @Rahul Narain  I got error message: Your browser does not support MathJax :(.

Comment: Wow, what version of Firefox are you using?

Comment: @Rahul Narain latest (3.6.12)... I know this is a strange bug in FF: it shows that I am using (3.6.12), but some sites detects my browser version as less than 2.0...:( I am going to reinstall it. :)

Comment: That is very strange! I'm afraid I'm out of specific ideas now. You could try going through the various troubleshooting steps listed at http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Basic%20Troubleshooting, particularly the one under "Make a new profile".

Comment: Additionally... what OS are you on?

Comment: @J. M. Windows XP

Comment: Can you check other browsers you may have installed to see if those have the same problem?

Comment: @J.M. On Google Chrome it works perfectly!

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't need any plug-ins to render the code. Please make sure you have enabled Javascript (since MathJax is a JS library), and the cache is not corrupt (try [clearing the cache](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/597/tex-broken-for-me)).